# Xaml Change text of TextBlock When Combobox Selection Change

Tags: xaml, combobox, datatrigger

I'm currently facing a problem in one of my Xaml Files. I created a combox with 2 fixed combobox Items. I also created a textblock. Here is the xaml code :

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" x:Name="UserSettingsConnectorGroupBoxProductTextBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Strings.UserSettingsConnectorGroupBoxProductText, Source={StaticResource StringLocalizer}}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,0,0"  />
    <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" x:Name="UserSettingsConnectorGroupBoxProductComboBox" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="300" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,5,0,0" SelectionChanged="UserSettingsConnectorGroupBoxProductComboBox_SelectionChanged" >
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Microsoft Deployment Toolkit" />
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Microsoft System Center Configuration Manager" />
    </ComboBox>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,0,0">
    <TextBlock Name="ConnectorTextBlock" Text="toto" Margin="0,5" >
        <TextBlock.Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=UserSettingsConnectorGroupBoxProductComboBox, Path=Text}" Value="Microsoft Deployment Toolkit">
                        <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Strings.UserSettingsConnectorGroupBoxProductTextBlockConnectorPathMDT, Source={StaticResource StringLocalizer}}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=UserSettingsConnectorGroupBoxProductComboBox, Path=Text}" Value="Microsoft System Center Configuration Manager">
                        <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Strings.UserSettingsConnectorGroupBoxProductTextBlockConnectorPathSCCM, Source={StaticResource StringLocalizer}}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBlock.Style>
    </TextBlock>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
        <TextBox Name="ConnectorTextBox" Margin="0,5" Width="300">
        </TextBox>
        <Button Content="Test" Margin="5" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <Button Content="Save" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,5" IsEnabled="False"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

And a preview :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x99Ba.png)

I would like the text of textBlock named "ConnectorTextBox" changes when the combobox Selected Item Changes. In order to do this, i created 2 datatriggers in TextBlock bound to "Text" Property of Combobox Control. Depending on the value of Text property, the Text value of textblock changes.

But it does not function. Only default value "Toto" is diplayed, even if i change my combobox Selection.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :) :)

Regis

Comment: Note : I used the same process to set the visibility and IsEnabled properties of others controls as textBoxes and buttons and it runs perfectly ... it seems that the problem occurs only on my textblock control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid setting `Text` property of `TextBlock`. Try this

```
<TextBlock Name="ConnectorTextBlock" Margin="0,5" >
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=UserSettingsConnectorGroupBoxProductComboBox, Path=Text}" Value="Microsoft Deployment Toolkit">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Strings.UserSettingsConnectorGroupBoxProductTextBlockConnectorPathMDT, Source={StaticResource StringLocalizer}}" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=UserSettingsConnectorGroupBoxProductComboBox, Path=Text}" Value="Microsoft System Center Configuration Manager">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Strings.UserSettingsConnectorGroupBoxProductTextBlockConnectorPathSCCM, Source={StaticResource StringLocalizer}}" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

If you want to set a default value, do it as below

```
<TextBlock Name="ConnectorTextBlock" Margin="0,5" >
                <TextBlock.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Setter Property="Text" Value="Toto" />
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=UserSettingsConnectorGroupBoxProductComboBox, Path=Text}" Value="Microsoft Deployment Toolkit">
                                <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Strings.UserSettingsConnectorGroupBoxProductTextBlockConnectorPathMDT, Source={StaticResource StringLocalizer}}" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=UserSettingsConnectorGroupBoxProductComboBox, Path=Text}" Value="Microsoft System Center Configuration Manager">
                                <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Strings.UserSettingsConnectorGroupBoxProductTextBlockConnectorPathSCCM, Source={StaticResource StringLocalizer}}" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </TextBlock.Style>
            </TextBlock>
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: I followed your advice and you put me on the right way. In reality DataTrigger runs perfectly but this the Localization which in not functional. If I replace the value of text by a fixed value it runs perfectly.
Now I have to understand why Localization does not return any value.

Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: Yes, I also tested it with a fixed value.

Comment: I Finally found the issue. I didn't set localized values correctly :-)